# importerror: couldn't import djano in windows powershell. im also using vscode

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell

when i enter in WINDOWS POWERSHELL, PS C:\djangoapps\test\venv\src> **python manage.py startapp ****stockmgmt**,
there's an error:

**importerror couldn't import django. are you sure it's installed and available in your PYTHONPATH environment variable? did you forget to activate a virtual environment?**

**how to solve this?**